# How to add double quotes around words-or-phrases-with-spaces-between-words?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Given the following string (Yes, STRING, not Array), I want to add double quotes around the names of countries.

`$string = "Array ( [0] => Array ( [nicename] => Afghanistan [phonecode] => 93 ) [1] => Array ( [nicename] => United States [phonecode] => 1 )"`;

I want the following string:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [nicename] => "Afghanistan" [phonecode] => 93 ) [1] => Array ( [nicename] => "United States" [phonecode] => 1 )
```

**How can I do that?**

***Note:***  This String shows only two countries, but the actual data will have more than a hundred counties.

I was thinking of doing something like

```
$string = preg_replace("/[[:alpha:]]/", "/\"[[:alpha:]]\"/", $string);
```

But the problem is that for the second argument, (1) how would PHP know what that character class `[[:alpha:]]` is and (2) The names of countries might contain spaces in addition to alphabetical characters.

Comment: Why is your string an array? In any event the found matches will be in their backreferences `$0` for what you've listed here. Regex/character classes dont go in the second parameter.

Comment: @chris85 I had a table in a database which contained data like countryName, countryCode, countryShortName, callingCode etc. I need only countryName and callingCode from it. So I wrote a little program to read those two columns from the database and printed them. That first string is what gets printed out. Now in my real project, I need to hard-code this array (can't read it from database or another resource). So I want to PRINT a string, which I can simply copy and paste in my code and assign to a variable. Hacky and dirty, but well tell me if you know a better way.

Comment: It's already in an organized format why cant you just use that?

Comment: @chris85 You hardcode arrays like `$variableName = "array ( [0] => array ( "nicename" => "Afghanistan", "phonecode" => 93 ), [1] => array ( "nicename" => "United States", "phonecode" => 1 ) )";`

Comment: @chris85 What I have is `Array ( [0] => Array ( [nicename] => Afghanistan [phonecode] => 93 ) [1] => Array ( [nicename] => United States [phonecode] => 1 )`. I can replace `[` with `, "`and `]` with `"`, but I also need to add double quotes around names of countries.

Comment: @chris85  "structure it as you need it" - How to do that! That's what I am trying to d that.

Comment: What is the status of this, answer didnt resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You should really be doing this where the array is built but it can be done with a regex...

You need to capture everything after `nicename` until a `[` or `)` (e.g. if the nicename is at the end or middle of the "array").

Using something like:

```
(\[nicename\] => )([^\[)]+)
```

should accomplish that, then you need to quote the found country name:

```
$1"$2"
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/7TeUQu/1

this has extra spaces after the country name since whitespace were allowed there. In PHP we'll need to use `preg_replace_callback` and the trim function to resolve this.

```
$regex = '/(\[nicename\] => )([^\[)]+)/';
$replace = '$1"$2" ';
$string = 'Array ( [0] => Array ( [nicename] => Afghanistan [phonecode] => 93 ) [1] => Array ( [nicename] => United States [phonecode] => 1 )';
$string = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($match) {
     return $match[1] . '"' . trim($match[2]) . '" ';
}, $string);
echo $string;
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/699678

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(\[nicename\] =>) ([a-zA-Z ]+) \[/', '$1 "$2" [', $string);
```

Comment: Answers should have explanations.